# splunklib.binding.HTTPError: HTTP 400 Bad Request -- Unknown search command 'index'

Tags: python, splunk-sdk

Error while running the search command

While using splunk enterprise, I want to run a search command from backend, keyword is "index = ". 
When I am running this command I am getting the result but when I am adding this command in my code, i am getting "splunklib.binding.HTTPError: HTTP 400 Bad Request -- Unknown search command 'index'."
I am able to login to splunk enterprise and can run a basic search command "search * | head 100"

```
def normal_search():
    #searchquery_normal = "search * | head 10"
    searchquery_normal = "index = some_tool_name"
    kwargs_normalsearch = {"exec_mode": "normal"}
    job = service.jobs.create(searchquery_normal, **kwargs_normalsearch)

    # A normal search returns the job's SID right away, so we need to poll for completion
    while True:
        while not job.is_ready():
            pass
        stats = {"isDone": job["isDone"],
                 "doneProgress": float(job["doneProgress"])*100,
                  "scanCount": int(job["scanCount"]),
                  "eventCount": int(job["eventCount"]),
                  "resultCount": int(job["resultCount"])}

        status = ("\r%(doneProgress)03.1f%%   %(scanCount)d scanned   "
                  "%(eventCount)d matched   %(resultCount)d results") % stats

        sys.stdout.write(status)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if stats["isDone"] == "1":
            sys.stdout.write("\n\nDone!\n\n")
            break
        sleep(2)

    # Get the results and display them
    for result in results.ResultsReader(job.results()):
        print result

    job.cancel()   
    sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Expected: No error
Actual:splunklib.binding.HTTPError: HTTP 400 Bad Request -- Unknown search command 'index'

.

Answer (score 4):

@PyPy2304

There should be a `search` command in the search query.
like this

`searchquery_normal = " search index = some_tool_name"`

For reference:

http://dev.splunk.com/view/python-sdk/SP-CAAAEE5

Comment: Let me know if you require further assistance. Please upvote and accept this answer if it helps you.
Happy Splunking